# Хочу сделать border-radius к элементу <nav>, но делается только к ссылке <a> Помогите пожалуйста разобраться в чем проблема

Tags: html, css

Хочу сделать border-radius к элементу , но делается только к ссылке  Помогите пожалуйста разобраться в чем проблема.

```css
nav {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


nav > ul {
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px solid #855a21;
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

nav > ul li {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
  
nav > ul li a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: rgb(229,187,129); /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(229,187,129,1) 0%, rgba(124,76,13,1) 70%, rgba(158,100,32,1) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(229,187,129,1) 0%,rgba(124,76,13,1) 70%,rgba(158,100,32,1) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(229,187,129,1) 0%,rgba(124,76,13,1) 70%,rgba(158,100,32,1) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#e5bb81', endColorstr='#9e6420',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 7px 15px 7px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #f4e2c8;
  outline: 1px solid #855a21;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

  
nav ul li a:hover {
    color: #4e2c1e;
    background: rgb(255,249,224);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,249,224,1) 0%, rgba(237,206,140,1) 39%, rgba(237,206,140,1) 79%, rgba(237,206,140,1) 79%, rgba(255,249,224,1) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,249,224,1) 0%,rgba(237,206,140,1) 39%,rgba(237,206,140,1) 79%,rgba(237,206,140,1) 79%,rgba(255,249,224,1) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(255,249,224,1) 0%,rgba(237,206,140,1) 39%,rgba(237,206,140,1) 79%,rgba(237,206,140,1) 79%,rgba(255,249,224,1) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fff9e0', endColorstr='#fff9e0',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
  }

 .submenu {
     display: none;
     position: absolute;
     left: 0px;
     top: 100%;
     padding: 0;
     border: none;
 }

 .submenu > li {
     width: 190px;
 }

 nav ul li:hover .submenu  {
    display: block;  
    border: 1px solid #bfa485;  
}

nav ul li:hover .submenu li a {
    border: none ;
    outline: none;
    background: #fcebc6;
    color: #4e2c1e;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}

nav ul li:hover .submenu li a:hover {
    background: #d8af75;
}

.topmenu .prices {
    
    border-right: none;
}

.topmenu .apllication {
    border-left: none;
    outline: none;
    padding-left: 250px;
    padding-right: 30px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul class="topmenu">
        <li><a href="#">ГЛАВНАЯ</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ПОДОБРАТЬ ПЕРСОНАЛ</a>
            <ul class="submenu">
                <li><a href="#">О НАС</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">ЗАДАТЬ ВОПРОС</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">ЭТО ИНТЕРЕСНО</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">ОТЗЫВЫ</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="prices">ЦЕНЫ</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#" class="apllication">ОСТАВИТЬ ЗАЯВКУ</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ОСТАВИТЬ ВАКАНСИЮ</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">КОНТАКТЫ</a></li>

    </ul>
</nav>
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/Flex_d1/pen/OJmELJL)

Comment: У вас радиус прописан только для ссылки. Поясните что вам мешает написать его для `nav` (что никак не будет заметно) или для `ul`.

Comment: В этом то и дело. Прописав в <nav> или в <ul> я не вижу этот радиус. А мне нужно, чтобы он появился, не могу понять, почему не видно....

Comment: Так его увидеть можно только если применить к тому элементу, который имеет фон или бордер. Родительские элементы никак не скругляют дочерние. Кроме случая если родитель сделать `overflow: hidden`, что здесь не пойдёт. И если задать для `ul` в вашем коде, то видно, как он скругляется сам.

Comment: Благодарю за помощь)

Comment: Стилизовать `nav` (см. заголовок вoпроса) вообще не очень ок, т.к. это семантический тег контейнера, он типа метовый. Я бы стилизовал именно вложенный в него `ul`.

Comment: @yar85 это суеверие. У `ul` тоже есть семантика. Чем его семантика лучше, что позволяет его стилизовать? Все повсеместно успешно их стилизуют, как и `header`, `footer`, `section` и так далее. По такой логике наверное вышло бы, что стилизовать можно только `div` и `span`.

Comment: _«Чем его семантика лучше, что позволяет его стилизовать?»_ - она не "лучше", она другая: `ul` это элемент разметки **контента**, который изначально имеет визуальное представление, тогда как `nav` - нет. Этим различием и обусловлена разумность стилизации `ul` вместо `nav`. Другими словами, `ul` находится "ближе" к размеченным данным, нежели класс метовых тегов "размечающих разметку" который здесь представлен тегом `nav`. Это совсем не то же самое, что "`section` vs `div`" и т.д., подобные сравнения просто неуместны.

Comment: _«Все повсеместно успешно их стилизуют»_ - очень весомый, взрослый аргумент (нет). В вебе очень много макак, но это не значит что мы тоже должны быть макаками из-за того что верстаем. Каждый сам выбирает, кем ему быть. Я лишь предлагаю следовать тому что написано в стандарте, а не копировать вредные заблуждения (типа "`aside` это то что расположено сбоку", и т.д.) потому что Вася и Петя так делают. Принимать такое предложение или нет - оставляю за личным выбором, и ничего не навязываю :)

Comment: @Pavel, ну а я вот называю - считая что не лишним будет учитывать такое явление как макаки (и опасность бездумного "быть как все", дабы случайно не пополнить собой ряды их Легиона). Прежде чем показывать пруфы, я попрошу соблюсти очередность, и предоставить пруф _"все повсеместно успешно стилизуют"_ - в виде репрезентативной стат. выборки, с каноничным определением успешности и ее доказательства в контексте исследования. А стандарт HTML с приложениями к нему - общедоступен (в отличие от вашей статистики), и вполне легко гуглится.

Comment: @yar85 ладно, я понял. Выборку такую конечно же я не предоставлю. Вы победили :)

Comment: @Pavel, предлагаю считать что победила дружба (не бензопила) и свобода, т.к. читающие так или иначе сделают свой собственный выбор в пользу одного из озвученных вариантов... что бы мы тут ни написали :)

Comment: @yar85 хорошо )